# CodeIgniter initial setup 404

Tags: php, codeigniter, routes

I just recently started learning CodeIgniter and trying to setup my project in this structure:

**Specification**
Apache/2.4.27 (Win64) PHP/5.6.31.
Server: WAMP Server 3 Localhost setup
CodeIgniter 3.1.2

**Directory**
`www/CI/firstci/******`

So using this directory structure will give me a 404 error when I navigate to `www/CI/firstci/`

> 404 Page Not Found The page you requested was not found.

If i put my CodeIgniter higher up the root like this

**Directory**
`www/firstci/******`

It will work when I navigate to `www/firstci/` and it will direct me to a welcome page.

So my question is how do I fix this routing/path problem? If possible explain why CodeIgniter behaves like this too?

Comment: `CI` is folder here?

Comment: Keep your project directly under www and then access like this: `www/firstci/******` This is the proper way. There is not benefit of keeping one extra folder `CI` and put the `firstci` inside it.

Comment: check your base URL in config. Nothing to do with fresh installation

Comment: @HimanshuUpadhyay There is no any matter like that. You can load your project where ever you want

Comment: @AbdullaNilam, you are right, but there is not any benefit to do that so I advised him.

Comment: @Photonic, are you using `.htaccess` file in your `firstci` folder?

Comment: What is your server's DocumentRoot set to?

Comment: Have you made sure you have the controller files named correct where the first letter only is upper case on class and filename https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/styleguide.html#file-naming you also may need a suitable htaccess for your project

Comment: Sorry guys made an edit, wrote the folder path wrong. Anyway is an initial setup so i have no htaccess setup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok i have found out that after i changed:

**routes.php**

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'welcome';
$route['404_override'] = '';
$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = FALSE;
```

TO

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'pages/view';
$route['(:any)'] = 'pages/view/$1';
$route['404_override'] = '';
$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = FALSE;
```

**Add a controller file called Pages.php**

```
class Pages extends CI_Controller {
    public function view($page = 'home') {
        if (!file_exists(APPPATH.'views/pages/'.$page.'.php')){
            show_404();
        }

        $data['title'] = ucfirst($page);

        $this->load->view('templates/header');
        $this->load->view('pages/'.$page, $data);
        $this->load->view('templates/footer');
    }
}
```

**Also added .htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|assets|images|js|css|uploads|favicon.png)
RewriteCond %(REQUEST_FILENAME) !-f
RewriteCond %(REQUEST_FILENAME) !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./index.php/$1 [L]
```

And added the relevant files to view folder organizing it to this structure:

```
templates/header
pages/'.$page, $data
templates/footer
```

It now works and is able to direct me to any php page

Answer (score 2):

Here ate some basic step to run CI Setup.

1. As mention in comment check your base URL in `config.php`
2. Follow this [Installation instructions](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/installation/index.html)
3. Here is the routing help link of [documentation](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/routing.html)
4. You can Remove the `index.php` file. here is the [documentation link](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/urls.html#removing-the-index-php-file)